# sqoop1 hung up when export hive table to mysql

Tags: cloudera-cdh

I run use sqoop1 of hue export hive table to mysql in CDH6.3.0.

Then get error without finish and export successfully.The same error happen in workflow, but workflow can be finished.

I run below command

```
export --connect jdbc:mysql://10.10.6.4:3306/poc?useSSL=false --username poc --password poc --table tt_ro_result --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/poc.db/tt_ro_impala --input-fields-terminated-by "\01" -m 3 --input-null-string "\\N" --input-null-non-string "\\N"
```

How to resolve this issue with below error message

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.runActionMain(LauncherAM.java:410)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.access$300(LauncherAM.java:55)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$2.run(LauncherAM.java:223)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.run(LauncherAM.java:217)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$1.run(LauncherAM.java:153)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.main(LauncherAM.java:141)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Intercepted System.exit(0)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.security.LauncherSecurityManager.checkExit(LauncherSecurityManager.java:57)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:107)
    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:971)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:214)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:199)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:104)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:51)
```